# Django rest_framework

Tags: forms, django-rest-framework

TypeError at /store/customers/
context must be a dict rather than ReturnList.

views.py

```
def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, template_name='store/hello.html' ,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

i want to render a form to create customer profile.